# Plot with switching regimes

Tags: python, plotly

I'm willing to create a plot which would look like this:

[image]

That is, I want it to contain shaded regions based on some condition.

If I take the following time series case (from plot.ly):

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

data = [go.Scatter(
          x=df.Date,
          y=df['AAPL.Close'])]

py.plot(data)
```

I would want it to display a shaded band whenever the process is below 100.
Is there a neat way of doing that?

Comment: Did you try the approach described here: https://plot.ly/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes?

Comment: No, I was not aware of that. Thank you, Max!